# XSLT Group distinct elements

Tags: html, xslt, xpath, grouping

I know there is a lot of links about grouping XSLT elements, but i coudn't make it work, and i am here to see if someone could give me a light.

I need to group a couple elements that have the same id.

My Database is like this:

[image]

The XSLT i have is this one, reading the database:

> http://pastebin.com/hAuEaskA

And this is the XML i GET:

> http://pastebin.com/4CrwsruZ

But i would like to group like this:

> http://pastebin.com/mBa6Gctf

Could someone give me a light?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 1.0 I would use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-id" match="item" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-id', @id)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@* | key('item-by-id', @id)/*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms

```
<root>
    <item id="questionario_atendimento_cordialidade">
        <quantidade id="2">1</quantidade>
        <nota id="3">1</nota>
    </item>
    <item id="questionario_atendimento_cordialidade">
        <quantidade id="2">1</quantidade>
        <nota id="3">2</nota>
    </item>
    <item id="questionario_atendimento_cordialidade">
        <quantidade id="2">3</quantidade>
        <nota id="3">3</nota>
    </item>
    <item id="questionario_atendimento_cordialidade">
        <quantidade id="2">8</quantidade>
        <nota id="3">4</nota>
    </item>
</root>
```

into

```
<root>
   <item id="questionario_atendimento_cordialidade">
      <quantidade id="2">1</quantidade>
      <nota id="3">1</nota>
      <quantidade id="2">1</quantidade>
      <nota id="3">2</nota>
      <quantidade id="2">3</quantidade>
      <nota id="3">3</nota>
      <quantidade id="2">8</quantidade>
      <nota id="3">4</nota>
   </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry the double posting, i updated my post so it's better understandable